# Having trouble deleting an item from a drop down list that comes from the database. Using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-delete, html.dropdownlistfor

In my program the admin has the ability to delete managers that are in a drop down list. I am having trouble getting the actual value to pass through when the button is clicked. Currently it passes a 'null' value. I want the value deleted from the database when the button is clicked.

MY VIEW

```
<div id="addManagerBox" class="admin-home-container-settings boxlike">
<div class="admin-home-itm-settings thinner">
    <h2>Add Project Manager</h2>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.manager, new {@class = "form-control" })
    <a id="btnAddManager" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary margintop">Add Manager</a>
</div>
<div class="admin-home-itm-settings thinner">
    <h2>Delete Project Manager</h2>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.selectedManager, Model.AllManagers,"--Select Project Manager--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    <button id="btnDeleteManager" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger margintop">Delete Manager</button>
</div>
```

AJAX CODE

```
    $("#btnDeleteManager").click(function () {
    $.post("/Settings/DeleteManager",
        {
            selectedManager: $('#selectedManager').val()
        },
        function (data) {
            if (data == "True") {

            } else {

            }
        });
});
```

MY MODEL VIEW

```
public class AppSettingsViewModel
{
    public string manager { get; set; }
    public string purpose { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [Display(Name = "RegisterEmail")]
    public string registerEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Project Manager is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Manager")]
    public string selectedManager { get; set; }        
    public List<Managers> allManagers { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> AllManagers { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Purpose is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Purpose")]
    public string selectedPurpose { get; set; }
    public List<Purposes> allPurposes { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> AllPurposes { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image History is required")]
    [Display(Name = "ImageHistory")]
    public string ImageHistory { get; set; }

    public List<Questions> allQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<Settings> allSettings { get; set; }


    public AppSettingsViewModel()
    {
        allSettings = new List<Settings>();
        allPurposes = new List<Purposes>();
        allManagers = new List<Managers>();
        allQuestions = new List<Questions>();
    }
}
```

CONTROLER

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool DeleteManager(string manager)
    {
        var managerRepo = new SiteContentRepository();

        return managerRepo.EditManager(manager, "delete");
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your controller code also?

Comment: added controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters are not matching. Your controller needs `manager` and you are passing `selectedManager`. Try this.

```
$.post("/Settings/DeleteManager",
{
   manager: $('#selectedManager').val()
},
function (data) {
   if (data == "True") {}  
   else {}            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your drop down an id value that matches what you are using in JQuery:

```
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "selectedManager" })
```

You're JQuery code:

```
manager: $('#selectedManager').val() //Changed this to accept the same named parameter as server side
```